# Getting ReportUnit to show attachments

Tags: nunit, reportunit

I've got an NUNIT test suite that properly generates an xml file with attachments, but can't find if there is a way to get ReportUnit to show those attachments in the rendered HTML.

Example - TestResult.xml contains:

```
<test-case id="0-1091" name="TestName" fullname="NUnitTestProject1.TestName" methodname="MethodName" classname="ClassName" runstate="Runnable" seed="92684126" result="Passed" start-time="2018-01-30 22:21:55Z" end-time="2018-01-30 22:21:55Z" duration="0.030017" asserts="5">
<properties />
<attachments>
<attachment>
<filePath>C:\Output\Result1.json</filePath>
<description><![CDATA[Request]]></description>
</attachment>
<attachment>
<filePath>C:\Output\Result2.png</filePath>
<description><![CDATA[Response]]></description>
</attachment>
</attachments>
</test-case>
```

It shows up when I run it in Visual Studio with the Name Outcome and Attachments

[Visual Studio Result](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kq59j.png)

But when I run ReportUnit on it the Attachments don't show up (in either passed tests or failed tests.)

Comment: ReportUnit would need to understand the format of the nunit result file better. Attachments are a fairly recent addition.

Comment: Thanks Charlie.  I assume by this you are saying it is not currently supported.  Do you know if this is something that is being looked into?

Comment: Just remembered you're the nunit guy not the reportunit guy.  I'll ask on the reportunit git.

Comment: ReportUnit was deprecated by extentreports-dotnet-cli just today. ReportUnit repo is also archived and it will no longer be possible to raise issues there. The project owner @anshooarora will be releasing both the sources and nuget package in a few days. This will support attachments afaik but as Charlie said, this would be something that would require checking how attachments are used in the NUnit results. Link: https://github.com/extent-framework/extentreports-dotnet-cli